# How to crop text from a scanned image using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, artificial-intelligence

I need to extract the bounding box of text and save it as sub-images of the main image. I am not getting the right code documentation for this task.

Please can anyone provide me code documentation or help links or any python modules which can help to crop text from scanned images.

Below I have attached a scanned image and expected output.

below image scanned copy need to crop text from image.

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd ='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract'
img = cv2.imread("test.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU | cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

rect_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (18, 18))
dilation = cv2.dilate(thresh1, rect_kernel, iterations = 1)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilation, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                                                cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

im2 = img.copy()
file = open("recognized.txt", "w+")
file.write("")
file.close()
for cnt in contours:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    rect = cv2.rectangle(im2, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cropped = im2[y:y + h, x:x + w] 
    file = open("recognized.txt", "a")
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(cropped)
    file.write(text)
    file.write("\n")
    crop_img = img[y:y+h, x:x+w] # just the region you are interested
    file.close
```

[image]

second image expected croped image:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Please show your code.

Comment: i tried by converting it to blackandwhite image. i dont knowhowto crop image.

Comment: @test did you get what you were expecting?

Answer (score 3):

Here is one approach in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Get the Canny edges
- Get the outer contours of the edges
- Filter the contours to remove small extraneous spots
- Get the convex hull of the main cluster of edges
- Draw the convex hull as white filled on a black background as a mask
- Mask to black the outside region of the input
- Get the rotated rectangle from the convex hull
- From the negative angle and center of the rotated rectangle rectify the orientation using perspective warping
- Save the results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read image
img = cv2.imread('receipt.jpg')
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]

# get edges
canny = cv2.Canny(img, 50, 200)

# get contours
contours = cv2.findContours(canny, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]

# filter out small regions
cimg = np.zeros_like(canny)
for cntr in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cntr)
    if area > 20:
        cv2.drawContours(cimg, [cntr], 0, 255, 1)

# get convex hull and draw on input
points = np.column_stack(np.where(cimg.transpose() > 0))
hull = cv2.convexHull(points)
himg = img.copy()
cv2.polylines(himg, [hull], True, (0,0,255), 1)

# draw convex hull as filled mask
mask = np.zeros_like(cimg, dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.fillPoly(mask, [hull], 255)

# blacken out input using mask
mimg = img.copy()
mimg = cv2.bitwise_and(mimg, mimg, mask=mask)

# get rotate rectangle
rotrect = cv2.minAreaRect(hull)
(center), (width,height), angle = rotrect
box = cv2.boxPoints(rotrect)
boxpts = np.int0(box)

# draw rotated rectangle on copy of input
rimg = img.copy()
cv2.drawContours(rimg, [boxpts], 0, (0,0,255), 1)

# from https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/20/text-skew-correction-opencv-python/
# the `cv2.minAreaRect` function returns values in the
# range [-90, 0); as the rectangle rotates clockwise the
# returned angle tends to 0 -- in this special case we
# need to add 90 degrees to the angle
if angle < -45:
    angle = -(90 + angle)

# otherwise, check width vs height
else:
    if width > height:
        angle = -(90 + angle)
    
    else:
        angle = -angle

# negate the angle to unrotate
neg_angle = -angle
print('unrotation angle:', neg_angle)
print('')
        
# Get rotation matrix
# center = (width // 2, height // 2)
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, neg_angle, scale=1.0)

# unrotate to rectify 
result = cv2.warpAffine(mimg, M, (ww, hh), flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, borderValue=(0,0,0))

# save results
cv2.imwrite('receipt_mask.jpg', mask)
cv2.imwrite('receipt_edges.jpg', canny)
cv2.imwrite('receipt_filtered_edges.jpg', cimg)
cv2.imwrite('receipt_hull.jpg', himg)
cv2.imwrite('receipt_rotrect.jpg', rimg)
cv2.imwrite('receipt_masked_result.jpg', result)

cv2.imshow('canny', canny)
cv2.imshow('cimg', cimg)
cv2.imshow('himg', himg)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('rimg', rimg)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Canny Edges:

[image]

Filtered Edges from Contours:

[image]

Convex Hull:

[image]

Mask:

[image]

Rotated Rectangle:

[image]

Rectified Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In OpenCV you can use `cv2.findContours` to draw the bounding boxes. See this article which explains how to do that: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/text-detection-and-extraction-using-opencv-and-ocr/

Then after you have your bounding box locations (your region of interest where text is located, and you want to crop) you can use use `slicing` to crop the image:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("lenna.png")
crop_img = img[y:y+h, x:x+w] # just the region you are interested
cv2.imshow("cropped", crop_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

If you want to extract the text directly, I think you can use `tesseract ocr` a python package (How to get started: https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/) . You can also make use of OpenCV built in OCR functions. Read more: https://nanonets.com/blog/ocr-with-tesseract/

Comment: Here is an article that explains it in detail how to retrieve the region where the text is located https://www.danvk.org/2015/01/07/finding-blocks-of-text-in-an-image-using-python-opencv-and-numpy.html

Answer (score 0):

```
from PIL import image
original_image = Image.open(".nameofimage.jpg")
rotate_image = Original_image.rotate(330)
rotate_image.show()
x = 100
y = 80
h = 200
w = 200
cropped_image = rotate_image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
cropped_image.show()
```